# Check if any nested Object has Value true and set it to false on click in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a button in template, if i click on that it should check all isActive values.

If any value found true, it should be changed to false.

My Vue script looks like this:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    rates: {
       a: {
           x: [40, 60],
           isActive: false
       },
       b: {
           x: [66, 76],
           isActive: false
       },
       c: {
           x: [76, 108],
           isActive: false
       }
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  changeToFalse() {
     // This is method
  }
}
```

My Template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @onclick="changeToFalse()"> Click Me </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Note:** Everything should be in changeToFalse() method, which i have created also that looping should be in this method only.

Thanks :)

Comment: and where's your `changeToFalse` function you mentioned?

Comment: edited, please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this to your code in your **method()**

```
changeToFalse() {
     // This is method
       for(let active in this.rates) {
          if(this.rates[active].isActive == true) {
                this.rates[active].isActive = false
             }
         console.log(this.rates[active].isActive)
     }
  }
```

Comment: why would you even check? just `this.rates.forEach(i => i.isActive = false)`

Comment: Would you be transforming your object into an array? Yes it should work then
https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/foreach-object#:~:text=JavaScript's%20Array%23forEach()%20function,values()%20%2C%20or%20Object.